# How can I connect an android tablet to the internet with a mobile broad band modem?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, android

I am in a remote location where the only possible way to access the internet is through a mobile broad band connection. I need to connect an android tablet to the internet, but it has no USB slot, so I cannot just plug the modem on it, besides at times I might need internet access simultaneously in both a desktop PC and the tablet, so it would be better if I could share the connection among this two devices. I have a TP-LINK TL-WR740N wireless router which I'm trying to use to do the trick, but I haven't being able to set it up right.

I'm connecting the PC to the router with a regular network cable, then sharing the internet connection with the wireless connection, then connecting the PC wirelesslly, after that I can connect the tablet to the LAN and access a small web page hosted on the PC however I don't have any internet access. I've being experimenting with different IP setups but no luck.

Like I said, I am on a remote location so I must do it with what I have, any ideas?

UPDATE:

The PC is running Windows 7, I've tried by setting up and ad hoc network but it is not detected by the tablet. I downloaded "Virtual Router" but it is unable to detect my broadband modem.

Comment: Are you able to hotspot your PCs internet connection when using the Mobile Broadband device?

Comment: What OS is the PC running?

Comment: does your tablet support usb otg? most of them have a special cable that breaks out for devices that use a regular USB connector

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm understanding you have the following equipment:

- Mobile broadband which has a USB connection where the PC may get internet via USB
- Wireless router
- Tablet and PC both need Internet

So, you can do the following:

- Connect mobile broadband to PC.  PC gets internet via mobile broadband.
- Connect wireless router to PC.  Log into wireless router's management interface and disable DHCP.  If you can't disable DHCP, flash this router to DD-WRT (it's supported) and disable DHCP.
- Setup wifi on wireless router as you need it.  Set WAN options on the wireless router to DHCP.
- Enable and setup Internet Connection Sharing on your PC (Not "virtual router")
- Connect WAN port of wireless router to your PC's NIC.

Your PC should then have working Internet, and share it to your tablet via the wireless router's AP.  Anything connected to the wireless should be getting an IP via the Internet Connection Sharing.  As a bonus you can plug in additional stuff to the LAN ports and share further.

Comment: If I disable DHCP the tablet is unable to get an IP address, the problem is that there's no obvious way to establish a fixed IP address on the tablet.

Comment: If you set it up the way above, anything on the access point should be pulling an IP from Windows ICS.  It'll use the built-in DHCP server in Windows ICS.  It won't work until you set up ICS.

Comment: I did it as much as possible as you recommended, but on the WAN options the only thing related with DHCP is an option that says: "Get IP with Unicast DHCP" which appears when I choose "Dynamic IP address", and which I made sure to enable. After setting it up I took care to plug the PC into the WAN port of the router, but the tablet is not getting any IP address.

Comment: Try moving it from the WAN port to one of the LAN ports.

Comment: No mater in which port I plug the PC, the tablet simply cannot get an IP address if DHCP disabled.

Answer (score 0):

How to Connect to Internet With Android - A Step by Step Guide
http://www.wikihow.com/Tether-With-Android

Comment: Welcome to Super User! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 0):

a lot of mobile device users in search of Internet access when they're not near a Wi-Fi hotspot. If you're one of these, you have three options:

- Use your smartphone as a broadband modem by tethering it to your device.
  Purchase a USB external mobile broadband adapter, along with a carrier service plan.
- Purchase a broadband wireless hotspot device (along with a carrier service plan), which creates a small Wi-Fi service zone and allows several (typically, up to four or five) devices to share the connection.

Answer (score 0):

Use your mobile phone as a hotspot. I'm assuming you have one if you are working remotely.

On a Samsung Andriod phone with 5.1.1 just go

```
Settings - Mobile hotspot and tethering - Mobile hotspot - On
```

This should make your phone discoverable by any wifi enabled device within range.

You should set a password as this will use your mobile data.  Make sure you turn it off when you have finished.